Deriving dispersion relation of hyperbolic material
I am trying to derive the following form of the dispersion relation for hyperbolic material: 
From the literature, this dispersion relation is achieved by setting the determinant of the below matrix to 0: (the below equations are from this paper: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0079672714000408)

However, I am struggling to arrive at this form.
When I set the determinant to 0, this is as far I can get:
$$ (k_y^2 k_z^2 + k_x^2 k_z^2)(k^2 - k_0^2 \varepsilon_\perp) + (k_x^2 + k_y^2 - k_0^2 \varepsilon_{zz} ) [k_x^2 k_y^2 - (k_y^2 + k_z^2 - k_0^2 \varepsilon_\perp)]$$
If someone sees a way to arrive at the dispersion relation shown at the top, I would appreciate it so much. Thanks!

You only have to replace $k_x^2 + k_y^2$ with $k_\perp^2$ again and again until there are no $k_x$ and $k_y$ left.
